# Where does Windows store its services data?

Tags: windows, service, version-control, registry, internals

Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Control_Manager) and other resources such as Windows Internals book, the SCM gets the data it presents in Services.exe by reading `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\ServiceGroupOrder\List` and   `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services`.

When you try to create your own process using `sc` command, the data in the registry seems to match the data you entered. When you cross the data seen in SCM's Services.exe tool, there is a lot of data I couldn't find elsewhere in the system.

For example, Eaphost.

Its display name in Services.exe says "Extensible Authentication Protocol" and it has a really long and descriptive description:

[image]

When you look in registry, you get the following, which shows a Description and DisplayName values that look more as a command rather than something else.

[image]

It's of course not only in the mentioned service, but in others also.

So, where does the SCM gets the rest of its data?

Comment: are you mean [*SHLoadIndirectString*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-shloadindirectstring) ?

Comment: @RbMm guess so. I extracted the resources. It didn't seem to have all this text..